# How to reject an element from an array which also contains hashes, in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Eg:

```
hash_var = ["1", "2", {"a" => ["aa", "bb", "cc"]}]
```

```
reject(hash_var, "1")             # should return ["2", {"a" => ["aa", "bb", "cc"]}]
reject(hash_var, "a")             # should return ["1", "2"]
reject(hash_var, {"a" => ["aa"]}) # should return ["2", {"a" => ["bb", "cc"]}]
```

Basically, I should be able to reject the element from the array, be it hash or array element.

Comment: It's not clear what you want here. Do you want to write a method that achieves your goals? Ruby's `reject` method won't do what you want.

Comment: reject method only removes the array element and not an hash if there's one. Yes, I need to write a method which accepts two arguments, first one being the array and second one being the element that I need to remove from the array. Second argument could be a simple array element or an Hash.

Comment: Seems like you want it to reject nested attributes.  I don't think you can do that.  Try manually looking for that element in `x` hash

Comment: This is the upteenth time I've seen a question expressed in terms of a single example, expecting the reader to fill in the blanks. Well over 90% of those questions have been ambiguous, and this one is not an exception. Please, state questions precisely and unambiguously in words, then give one or more examples for illustration, showing the desired result for each.  Are we to assume that `hash_val` is always an array of strings and hashes, each hash having a single key-value pair, the key a string and the value an array of strings and that...

Comment: ...`reject`'s second argument to always be a string or a hash, the hash to always have a single key-value pair, the key being a string and the array to contain one or more strings? If not, what other structures could `hash_val` and the second argument of `reject` have?

Comment: Yes, the second argument will have only a string or an hash and the hash will always be a single key value pair one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use delete mehod on hash like

```
hash_var = ["1", "2", {"a" => ["aa", "bb", "cc"]}]
hash_var.delete("1") //this will delete 1 from hash then new value of hash will be ["2", {"a"=>["aa", "bb", "cc"]}]
hash_var[1]["a"].delete("aa") //this will give output ["2", {"a"=>["bb", "cc"]}]
```

and so on according to your use

Comment: Cannot locate hashes with array index as it can be anywhere and it's a relative huge array

Answer (score 0):

That should do the job

```
hash_var.drop_while { |e| e == '1' }
hash_var.reject { |e| e == '1' }
hash_var.find_all { |e| e != '1' }
hash_var.select { |e| e != '1' }
```

Comment: but this logic won't work if I need to remove the hash from the array

Answer (score 0):

You could define the instance method `Enumerable#dig_drop`:

```rb
arr = ["1", "2", {"a" => ["aa", "bb", "cc"]}, {"b" => ["aa", "bb"]}]

module Enumerable
  def dig_drop(*elm)
    self.each_with_index {|_, idx|
      unless self[idx].respond_to? :dig
        self.delete(elm[0])
        next
      end
      last=elm.pop
      if elm.empty?
        self[idx].delete(last)
      else
        self[idx].dig(*elm).nil? ? nil : self[idx].dig(*elm).delete(last)
      end
    }
    self.reject!(&:empty?)
  end
end

arr.dig_drop "1"         # arr equals ["2", {"a" => ["aa", "bb", "cc"]}, {"b" => ["aa", "bb"]}]
arr.dig_drop('a')        # arr equals ["2", {"b" => ["aa", "bb"]}]  
arr.dig_drop('b', 'bb')  # arr equals ["2", {"b" => ["aa"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this method should work:

```rb
def reject(hash_var, ele)
  # Find the index of the ele
  # If it is found, just remove it and return hash_var
  idx = hash_var.index(ele)
  if idx
    hash_var.delete_at(idx)
    return hash_var
  end

  # Convert the hashes to arrays - 2D arrays
  # { "b" => "2" } becomes [["b", "2"]]
  (0...hash_var.length).each do |n|
    if hash_var[n].class == Hash
      hash_var[n] = hash_var[n].to_a
    end
  end

  (0...hash_var.length).each_with_index do |n, i|
    # Only operate if hash_var[n] is an array
    # this means that this is 2D array i.e. hash
    if hash_var[n].class == Array
      # If this is just as element, delete the whole hash_key
      # i.e. reject(hash_var, "a")
      # here ele = "a", so since this is not hash
      # we need to delete full element i.e. ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
      if hash_var[n][0][0] == ele
        hash_var.delete_at(i)
      else
        next if ele.class == String
        ele_a = ele.to_a
        if hash_var[n][0][0] == ele_a[0][0]
          diff = hash_var[n][0][1] - ele_a[0][1]
          hash_var[n][0][1] = diff
        end
      end
    end
  end

  ## Convert the 2D arrays back to hashes
  (0...hash_var.length).each do |n|
    if hash_var[n].class == Array
      hash_var[n] = hash_var[n].to_h
    end
  end

  # return final
  return hash_var
end
```

Tests:

```rb
hash_var = ["1", "2", {"a" => ["aa", "bb", "cc"]}]
p reject(hash_var, "1")
# => ["2", {"a"=>["aa", "bb", "cc"]}]

p reject(hash_var, "a")
# => ["1", "2"]

p reject(hash_var, {"a" => ["aa"]})
# => ["1", "2", {"a"=>["bb", "cc"]}]
```